# How does Genesis 22:17 "the stars of heavens"tie to Rev. 6:13 when the stars fell to earth?

Tags: genesis, revelation

As the New Testament is the Old Testament revealed, and the Old Testament is the New Testament concealed, and as God's prophesies are revealed in the New Testament, then in light of Gen. 22:17 where God promised that He would multiply Abraham's seed as the "stars of the heavens", then what does the prophesy of Rev. 6:13 mean when it says "the stars of heaven fell to earth?"

Comment: The headline question is fine, but the explanation is opinion based. For many Christians as well as virtually all Jews, the OT is not the NT 'concealed' etc. I'll be happy to remove my downvote it the OP is edited to stick to the actual question.

Comment: When most of the NT scriptures are linked to or direct quotes from the OT scriptures, the two cannot be separated.  God's word is consistent throughout both covenants, and the prophetic apocalyptic language He used repeats.  Connecting the dots is not opinion, but recognition.

Comment: Some interpretative traditions state that the Revelation is like a *history* rather than only foretelling. So this interpretation has many events in the Book of Revelation stand as things that have already happened. In this case, they could very well be the same thing.

Comment: @DanFefferman I believe the question gets to set the framework. So this question is clearly *not* soliciting answers from the "many Christians as well as virtually all Jews, [who do not believe] the OT is the NT 'concealed' etc." Answers may address that interpretative tradition, but only after they have addressed the interpretative tradition requested.

Comment: Expanding on my first comment above, I think many take the Revelation "stars" as allusion to the fall of Lucifer and his followers, which clearly had nothing to do with Abraham. I think a minority might make a connection with Nephilim (literally "fallen ones"), which again had nothing to do with Abraham. Both are highly discussed verses.

Answer (score 6):

There have been several understandings of "the stars" in Rev 6:13.  Let me list a few of which I am aware.

However, before doing that, I observe that Rev 6:13 and Gen 22:17 have very little in common except "stars of the heavens".  This is a common metaphor of being uncountable as the next one beside it.  That is, Abraham is being told that his descendants would be as uncountable as:

- the stars in the sky
- the grains of sand on the sea-shore.

This means that Abraham's descendants are NOT being associated with stars and grains of sand, except in number.  See also Deut 28:62 to confirm this.  (Nah 3:16 uses the same metaphor for others as well.)  Further, the "stars of heaven" is used to denote false worship as per 2 Kings 21:3, Jer 8:2, Acts 7:42, Rev 12:4.  Lastly, the prophecy in Gen 22:17 is said to have been fulfilled in Deut 1:10, 10:22, 1 Chron 27:23, Heb 11:12.

Now back to the meaning of Rev 6:13 -

**Context**

The context implied in Rev 6:12-14 are both internal (to Revelation) and external (other parts of the Bible) as follows:

- Isa 13:10 - For the stars of heaven and their constellations will not give their light. The rising sun will be darkened, and the moon will not give its light.
- Isa 34:4 - All the stars of heaven will be dissolved. The skies will be rolled up like a scroll, and all their stars will fall like withered leaves from the vine, like foliage from the fig tree.
- Isa 24:19, 23 - The earth is utterly broken apart, the earth is split open, the earth is shaken violently. ... The moon will be confounded and the sun will be ashamed; for the LORD of Hosts will reign on Mount Zion and in Jerusalem, and before His elders with great glory.
- Joel 2:31 - The sun will be turned to darkness and the moon to blood before the coming of the great and awesome Day of the LORD.
- Hag 2:6-7 - Yet once, it is a little while, and I will shake the heavens and the earth, and the sea, and the dry land, and I will shake all nations, and the desire of all nations shall come; and I will fill this house with glory, saith the Lord of hosts.
- Dan 12:2, 3 - And many who sleep in the dust of the earth will awake, some to everlasting life, but others to shame and everlasting contempt. Then the wise will shine like the brightness of the heavens, and those who lead many to righteousness will shine like the stars forever and ever.
- Heb 12:26, 27 - At that time His voice shook the earth, but now He has promised, “Once more I will shake not only the earth, but heaven as well.” The words “Once more” signify the removal of what can be shaken—that is, created things—so that the unshakable may remain.
- Rev 1:20 - This is the mystery of the seven stars you saw in My right hand and of the seven golden lampstands: The seven stars are the angels of the seven churches, and the seven lampstands are the seven churches.

The above list is not exhaustive.  Based on this, I have heard the following interpretations:

1. **Literal**

The falling stars refer to a meteor shower and the earthquake is literal.  The darkening of the sun would then refer to an eclipse and the red moon is a lunar eclipse.  All these, say these interpreters, are signs immediately before the second coming of Jesus.

[The problem with this, is the "sky rolling up" and the many times that all these literal things have occurred since Jesus' resurrection.]

2. **Metaphoric Preterist**

Some preterists, specifically those who do not make the above signs literally apply to Jesus's death or the destruction of Jerusalem, understand the falling stars as the breakup of an existing leadership order and change to a new one.  That is, the change from the Israelite covenant to the new covenant and the massive disruption that involved in leadership of God's people.

3. **Metaphoric Eschatalogical #1**

This idea takes these "signs" as a piling of metaphors showing the cataclysmic events, societal, political, ecclesiastical, and physical that will occur just before the return of Jesus, including collapse of governments, economic woes and environmental woes.

4. **Metaphoric Eschatalogical #2**

Some understand Rev 6:12-14, especially on the basis of Rev 1:20, to predict the collapse of organized churches and religion and take evidence of this in the dying state of many traditional churches.  (There might be some precent for this in Peter's remarks in Acts 2:17-20.)

This is far from an exhaustive list.  The choice from among the above options will be greatly influenced by one pre-conditioning, assumptions and eschatological framework.

In contradistinction to Isa 25:9 where the righteous are elated to see the coming of the Lord, the wicked in Rev 6:15-17 ask to be destroyed.  Therefore, my personal preference is similar to option #3 above.

Comment: But, Dottard, it is not our view point that matters.  It is God's own definitions that His word reveals.  It is not up to us to decide His definitions, but to find them.

Comment: @Gina - I fully agree.  But human biases still get in the way - none us is completely objective.

Comment: @Dottad, Human biases are definetely a problem.  But we strive here at this hermeneutic site to discover the true meaning of God's word as His word is our standard.  So all of man's biases have to be discarded when identified... right?

Comment: @Gina - agreed - but that is the trickiest part!  See Rom 7.

Comment: I would add one more possible interpretation of the Revelation verse. Atmospheric pollution would obscure the sun and moon and cause the stars of heaven to *appear* to vanish from the sky.

Answer (score 3):

The saying alluded to is actually, "The New is in the Old concealed; the Old is in the New revealed." (That was stated only last weekend by a minister preaching on 2 Samuel 2:1-5 as the O.T. text, and 2 Peter 1:12-21 as the N.T. text.)

However, it does not follow that we could take every verse in the O.T. that mentions 'stars' and seek to relate them to the N.T. Revelation 6:13 verse that mentions stars falling to earth. We could not even take the one O.T. verse in this question, supposing that Revelation 6:13 should automatically 'reveal' what the Genesis verse meant. Unless both verses are speaking about the same things, then it is only personal opinion that they are - unless a case is first made, from scripture, that they are.

The Genesis 'stars' speak of the huge numbers of human descendants of Abraham that God promised he would eventually have. The Revelation stars speak symbolically of end-time events prior to Christ's return to Earth. In view of this, a case would first have to be made from scripture that either that was not true, or that there are hints to be found in both texts that indicate they are speaking of the same thing. Given that there appears to be nothing to indicate that, **my answer to the question is, "The Genesis 22:17 'stars' do not tie to the Revelation 6:13 'stars'."**

Comment: Need to follow the patterns of God's word, Anne.

Comment: @Gina It appears you already have decided to accept your own viewpoint on the connection of OT to NT as a rule to be followed. Thus you continue to advocate for each answer to accept your initial statement that is not supported by any specific scriptural text. Maybe these things are an example or a spiritual drama, but to force a specific  "rule" to scripture interpretation limits a persons ability to expand their understanding of the deeper things of God. Many words and phrases have multiple meanings and applications andf do not all fit into a nicely tied up package. IMO

Comment: @ACME - Hmmm, God's definitions are set within His scriptures, and I would hesitate to want to expand my thinking beyond His scriptures.  That is a problem that has led many off the path, wandering into doctrines of men.  Very easy thing to walk off the straight and narrow way.

Comment: @Gina and yet you hold to an erroneous man made rule.  All can be fooled by their own perceived wisdom.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When speaking to Abraham, God **does not** say *stars of heaven*:

> I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply your offspring as the stars of heaven **and** as the sand that is on the seashore. And your offspring shall possess the gate of his enemies (Genesis 22:17)
> כי־ברך אברכך והרבה ארבה את־זרעך ככוכבי השמים וכחול אשר על־שפת הים וירש זרעך את שער איביו

God says, it is stars of the heaven **and** sand of the sea. Moreover, the Hebrew word, שמים usually rendered as *heaven* here is actually **plural**; a literal understanding would be *the heavens*.

On the other hand, the Greek in Revelation is οὐρανοῦ, which is **singular**. It is true, שמים is always plural and so may be understood as either singular or plural, but the Greek οὐρανοῦ may be written as either singular or plural. Therefore, in addition to the possibility the phrase should be intended symbolically, as is often the case in apocalyptic passages, attempting to make a rigid literal connection between Genesis 22:17 and Revelation 6:13 fails in two ways:

- Genesis includes the addition of *sand of the sea* which is lacking in Revelation.
- Revelation avoids the plural οὐρανοῦ, demonstrating it was not made as a literal comparison to Genesis. (This assumes in making the type of comparison as the OP does the obvious difference that Genesis was given in Hebrew and Revelation in Greek may be ignored.)

Finally, should one attempt to make a rigid and literal comparison of the two expressions, as the OP suggests is appropriate, one must acknowledge Revelation speaks of **only in part** of what was promised in Genesis. The offspring which are as *numerous as the sand of the sea* are not included in what is spoken of in Revelation.

Answer (score 0):

To echo others’ answers but from a different perspective, it feels like you are trying to compile a “biblical theology of stars.” The challenge with this is that the bible is not about stars, but about the Kingdom of God. So, whilst it is fascinating to create such a set, the “chemical bonds” between its components cannot be too strong, lest wrong conclusions be drawn.

Comment: This answer should really be a comment but I don’t have enough reputation for that I’m afraid. Seems like I am able to comment on my own answer, however. Ergo…

Comment: My pt is - It's a metaphor.  God called the children of Abraham the stars of the heavens.  In prophesy, falling stars meant removal from political and civic authority especially of the Levitical and Jewish hierarchy.  It is not literally speaking of stars falling from the sky.

Comment: The thing is though… If you take them as purely metaphoric in Revelation, where does that leave us with the epistolary versions of the same story in the letters? The earth does meet with a fiery end, agreed? The clear should interpret the unclear?

Comment: No.  That is incorrect.  In prophesy, "earth" is the land/territory the prophet is warning, & in 2 Pet. 3 as in most other OT prophesy it stands for Israel / Judea/Jerusalem.  The elements is the Gr word "stoicheion" (G4747) & means the worship under the Mosaic law - not the Greek elements of earth, wind, fire & water.  The prophesy was the burning of Jerusalem & temple to destroy the practice of all of the animal sacrifices at that temple.  Was never speaking about the end of the physical cosmos.  See: https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/04/28/frequent-mistakes-part-vi-the-end-of-the-world-or/

Answer (score -1):

God defined His metaphors in the Old Testament by using comparisons with the words “like” and “as.”  In Genesis 22:17, God promised to multiply Abraham’s descendants to be as numerous **as** the “stars of the heavens” and as the “sand which is on the sea-shore” (YLT).  The first comparison to the “stars of the heavens” was repeated throughout the Old Testament when speaking of the children and tribes of Israel.

God reaffirmed this oath with Jacob/Israel in Genesis 26:4, so that we know the meaning of the metaphor continues to represent the descendants/tribes of Israel. It is affirmed again in Ex. 32:13.  God said He had already multiplied them “as the stars of the heavens” in Deuteronomy 1:10, and again in Deuteronomy 10:22 as a past accomplishment.

The metaphor continues to be used for the children of Israel in 1 Chronicles 27:23, and Nehemiah 9:23 that God had already multiplied them “as the stars of the heavens.”

Joseph’s dream of his father, mother, and brothers bowing to him in Genesis 37:9-10 establishes a further meaning for ruling authorities as the sun, moon, and stars. <sup>1</sup>

> <sup>**9**</sup> And he dreameth yet another dream, and recounteth it to his brethren, and saith, 'Lo, I have dreamed a dream again, and lo, the sun and the moon, and eleven stars, are bowing themselves to me.' 10 And he recounteth unto his father, and unto his brethren; and his father pusheth against him, and saith to him, `What [is] this dream which thou hast dreamt? do we certainly come -- I, and thy mother, and thy brethren -- to bow ourselves to thee, to the earth?' (YLT)

Jacob/Israel interprets the meaning of the dream for us, that he as the head of the family/government or ruling unit was the sun; that the mother, or next highest ruler was the same as the moon; and that his brothers, or third highest of the family unit were the stars.  That they would bow down to the earth meant they would be subject to Joseph in the future.  (This prophesy did not say they would fall to the earth, but only bow down to the earth.)

This dream comparison established the metaphors God would use for His prophecies against nations/tribes.  The darkening of the sun is the removal of the king of that nation from his position of authority and rule.  The moon not giving her light is the removal from power of the Queen or second-highest ruler.  The stars falling to earth was the removal of the third-highest of the king’s court for princes, governors, and magistrates.

To know which king, queen, or princes would be overthrown depends upon which nation/earth God was about to bring into judgment.  In Isa. 13:9-10 we have the prophecy of the fall of the king of Babylon,

> <sup>**9**</sup> Lo, the day of Jehovah doth come, Fierce, with wrath, and heat of anger, To make the land become a desolation, Yea, its sinning ones He destroyeth from it. <sup>**10**</sup> For the stars of the heavens, and their constellations, Cause not their light to shine, Darkened hath been the sun in its going out, And the moon causeth not its light to come forth.  (YLT)

Where the specific land of this prophesy was Babylon, the darkened sun was the king of Babylon, the moon was the queen or next highest governor, and the stars of his “heavens” were the princes/magistrates of the king's dominion/rule.  It is the standard judgment language God would use for the downfall of a nation.

In the context of the specific prophesy, the earth is the land or region/territory of that specific nation <sup>1</sup>, and the “heavens” were the ruling authority or dominion of the king’s court over that land.  The word "earth" did not apply to all of the lands on the entire face of God’s creation, but only to the specific land God was about to judge/destroy.

In speaking to the children of Israel in Deuteronomy 32:1, Moses said,

> Give ear, O ye heavens, and I will speak; and hear, O earth, the words of my mouth…. (KJV)

The word “heavens” was not addressing God in His heaven above.  Moses was not giving God instructions.  Moses was addressing two classes of the people: the heavens were the host of heaven which God had established through the priesthood that was to teach and govern the people as His representatives, and the “earth” were the people of the congregation/land/territory. <sup>2</sup>

This holds true throughout the prophesies, no matter which country or nation or tribe is under judgment.  We have to know which land the prophet was sent to warn in order to know which “heaven” or “heavenly place” or “host of heaven” would be overthrown.

In Isaiah 13:10, the “heavens” referred to the ruling authority of the king of Babylon, and all his court.  Kings rule at God’s pleasure (Daniel 2:21).  Kings have dominion over a part of God’s earth.  As God rules over all the earth, the king rules over a small part which God refers to in the prophesies as the king’s “heaven” or “heavenly places.”

So the “trembling of heavens” and “shaking the earth from its place” in Isaiah 13:13 was the overthrow of the king’s dominion and authority, and the destruction of the land nation of Babylon.

However, for the most part in the Old Testament, “earth” was synonymous with Israel and Jerusalem.  For instance, in Jeremiah 6:19, Jeremiah was warning Jerusalem of God’s anger:

> Hear, O earth, lo, I am bringing evil on this people, The fruit of their devices, For to My words they gave no attention, And My law — they kick against it. (YLT)

The “earth” was the people of Jerusalem… the city to be inspected (vs. 6), the remnant of Israel (vs.9). And, again in Jeremiah 6:22,

> Thus said Jehovah: Lo, a people hath come from a north country, And a great nation is stirred up from the sides of the earth.  (YLT)

The sides of the “earth” were specifically concerning the prophecy against Jerusalem, the “earth” of verse 19 of the same chapter.  This is not the sides of all of the earth, but only the borders of Jerusalem, the remnant of Israel.  And, once more in Jeremiah16:19, speaking of Jerusalem,

> O Jehovah, my strength, and my fortress, And my refuge in a day of adversity, Unto Thee nations do come from the ends of earth, And say, Only falsehood did our fathers inherit, Vanity, and none among them is profitable.

The “ends of the earth” only had meaning for the borders of the land that was under judgment.  The ends of the earth in Jer. 16:19 were the borders of Judea and Jerusalem. This same method of judgment and overthrow of kingdoms and lands carries through to His prophesies in the New Testament.  In the prophecy of the destruction of the temple in Jerusalem,

Matthew 24:29

> And immediately after the tribulation of those days, the sun shall be darkened, and the moon shall not give her light, and the stars shall fall from the heaven, and the powers of the heavens shall be shaken; (YLT)

Mark 13:24-25

> <sup>**24**</sup> But in those days, after that tribulation, the sun shall be darkened, and the moon shall not give her light, <sup>**25**</sup> and the stars of the heaven shall be falling, and the powers that are in the heavens shall be shaken. (YLT)

The metaphors are the same.  The sun is the king, or highest ruling authority of the specific land area, Jerusalem; the moon was the next highest authority, or the Sanhedrin, and the stars were the next highest authority, the priesthood and all of their associated governors/magistrates that ruled over the people of Jerusalem, all grouped together as the “stars” of that heaven, that dominion over that land of Judea and the city of Jerusalem.

Falling to earth was their removal from their “heaven” or dominion and rule over that land.  It is not literally speaking of the twinkling lights in the nighttime sky being thrown down to earth in meteor showers.  Those “stars” or princely rulers would be subjected to judgment and no longer have any authority to rule over the people of the land/earth.  It does not apply to the entire earth.  This prophecy was specific to Jerusalem and that temple.

**Addition:**

Excerpt from [Benson's Commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/mark/13-24.htm) at Mark 13:24-25:

> Our Lord having, in the preceding part of his discourse, given his disciples a particular account of the various circumstances which should precede and accompany the destruction of Jerusalem, proceeds now to describe the dissolution of the Jewish polity, and the abolition of the Mosiac economy, in all the pomp of language and imagery made use of by the ancient prophets, when they foretold the overthrow of cities and states. The expressions are highly figurative, and signify the passing away of all the glory, excellence, and prosperity of the nation: and the introduction of universal sadness, misery, and confusion; that the Jewish polity, both civil and religious, should be destroyed; that the Jews should be no more a people, united under a form of government administered by themselves, and possessing their own country.

It is the same meaning in Revelation 6:13.  We identify who the prophet was in Revelation, and to which land/earth/people the warning of judgment applied.

Excerpt from [Barne's Notes](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/revelation/6-13.htm) on Rev. 6:13:

> Stars, in the Scriptures, are symbols of princes and rulers (see Daniel 8:10; Revelation 8:10-11; Revelation 9:1); and the natural meaning of this symbol is, that there would be commotions which would unsettle princes, and bring them down from their thrones - like stars falling from the sky.

The prophet of Revelation was Christ.  Revelation 1:1, *“A revelation of Jesus Christ, that God gave to him,….”*

We remember that Jesus implied that he was a prophet in Matthew 13:57, *“And Jesus said to them, 'A prophet is not without honor except in his own country, and in his own house:'”*

So, Christ was the prophet speaking and providing the warning in Revelation.  He gave it to John, and told John that he would again prophesy and tell the people of this warning and coming of judgment (Revelation 10:11). He called Himself a prophet, and He sent His disciples out to prophesy by His authority that the kingdom was at hand in the first century A.D.  He told John that He would show him things that would shortly come to pass (Revelation 1:1) and that the time was at hand (Revelation 1:3). Jesus told John that those who pierced Him would see Him (Revelation 1:7) and that all the tribes of the land would mourn.  The tribes of the land were of Judea and Jerusalem where Christ was crucified.

In Revelation 1:4, Jesus told John where to go… to the seven churches of Asia.  These are specifically identified in verse 11,

> Saying, I am Alpha and Omega, the first and the last: and, What thou seest, write in a book, and send it unto the seven churches which are in Asia; unto Ephesus, and unto Smyrna, and unto Pergamos, and unto Thyatira, and unto Sardis, and unto Philadelphia, and unto Laodicea. (KJV)

He was sending John to tell them the joyful news that He was coming quickly, just as had been promised to the Hebrew Christians in Heb 9:28 for His second appearance in that generation; just as He had told His disciples that some would still be living to see Him coming in His kingdom (Matthew 16:28), just as He had told them that John would live to see His coming (John 21:22).

So, what we next must identify is which land was going to be destroyed.  Which earth was the prophet speaking about for the destruction and desolation that would soon happen? One of the very first clues is in Revelation chapter 7, as verse 1 speaks of the four messengers or angels that are standing on the *“four corners of the earth”*, and holding back the winds that they should not blow.  Think “winds of war”, or “winds of stormy weather”.  And, think also of the four corners as the borders of the specific earth under judgment.

Revelation 7:3

> …till we have sealed the servants of our God in their foreheads.  (KJV)

Which servants of God, and where were they?  Those sealed of God were those called out of the twelve tribes of Israel.  (Revelation 7:4-8).  Where were the called of God, those called out of the tribes of Israel living?  Judea, and the surrounding lands of Palestine and Asia.

The next clue is the temple of God in Revelation 11, where John is told to measure it, but not to measure the outer court where the nations (Gentiles) would tread for 42 months.  Where was the temple of God?  It was in Jerusalem.

The next clue is Revelation 11:8,

> And their dead bodies shall lie in the street of the great city, which spiritually is called Sodom and Egypt, where also our Lord was crucified. (KJV)

Jesus was crucified just outside of Jerusalem, and the verse compares Jerusalem spiritually to the wicked and evil people of Sodom and Egypt which had previously come under the wrath of God’s judgment. The entire prophecy of Revelation, the testimony of Jesus Christ, was about the destruction of Jerusalem, Judea, and their temple.  That destruction occurred in 70 AD at the hands of the Romans, who were the agents of God, His tools, and messengers.

So, all of the metaphorical prophetic elements of “earth” were speaking of Judea and Jerusalem.  They do not apply to the entire world.  The four corners of the earth in Revelation 7:1 were therefore the borders of Judea. The better translation of Revelation 7:1 is from Young’s Literal Translation:

> And after these things I saw four messengers, standing upon the four corners of the land, holding the four winds of the land, that the wind may not blow upon the land, nor upon the sea, nor upon any tree;

Just as in Ezekiel 7, the land was Judea, and the four corners were the borders of Judea, and the judgment would fall upon all of Judea.

Therefore, the stars that fell to earth in Revelation 6:13 were the Jewish authorities of the Sanhedrin who had crucified Christ in Jerusalem.  The earth was Jerusalem.  That battle was engaged between the ruling authorities of the Sanhedrin and temple priesthood of Jerusalem and the opposing army of Rome.  The “heavens” were the dominion of the Roman Caesar (Nero) and the Sanhedrin authorities. The “heaven” of the Roman empire was the kings of Revelation 17:10, who were the kings or Caesars of Rome who ruled over the “earth” of Judea.

Stars falling to earth had nothing to do with angels or heavenly messengers being thrown out of God’s heaven above.  Falling to earth was prophetic judgment language of rulers and kings and princes whose political stations were plucked up and thrown down (Jeremiah 1:10; 12:17; 31:28;  Ezekiel 19:12’) Revelation 6:13 referred to the same "stars of the heavens" of Genesis 22:17 and their power was shattered (Daniel 12:7) at the destruction of their temple in Jerusalem in 70 AD.

See more at [Revelation: The Four Corners of The Earth](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/05/29/revelation-the-four-corners-of-the-earth/)

Notes:

1. Earth - [Strong's H776](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/776.htm) "eretz"
2. [Clarke’s commentary](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/acc/daniel-8.html) on Dan. 8:10:

“The host of heaven — The Jewish hierarchy. The stars, the priests and Levites. The powers or host of heaven are probably intended by our Lord, Matthew 24:29, to signify the whole Jewish hierarchy.”  Source:

Comment: You spoke to Dottard about eliminating biases, yet you start with the assumption that this is a metaphor and only metaphor? There are some very obvious problems to your post but I will credit you on what I consider an interesting interpretation, which I don’t preclude from being a possible way of reading the text. However to deny the literal sense of the reading altogether is troubling. “a great star fell from heaven, blazing like a torch, and it fell on a third of the rivers and on the springs of water. The name of the star is Wormwood”
‭‭Rev8‬:‭10‬-‭11‬ ‭stars come to earth literally

Comment: I want to respond to this question but I don’t quite understand it yet and as I read it most people would not be ready to accept the response I would post. You especially it seems based on the previous discussion. I mean do you deny the Trinity too? It has pagan parallels but I still can prove the Trinity from the Hebrew especially with the grammar that the Trinity is OT even if there are pagan versions of it, just as there are pagan versions of the world flood or a baby in a basket, these doesn’t  preclude Moses from being in a reed basket, maybe his mother was inspired by that pagan story.

Comment: Bias: a particular tendency, trend, inclination, feeling, or opinion, especially one that is preconceived or unreasoned:   The tendency to try to make everything in God's word literal is a bias.  God's words are literal words, but His own comparisons of the children of  Israel to the stars of the heavens does not mean that the children of Israel were literally stars.  The star called wormwood in Rev. 8:10-11 is figurative, and is single so it represents one man that would cause the death of a third of the people.  Jer. 9:15; 23:15; Lam. 3:15; 3:19.  God promised He would feed them wormwood.

Comment: We would think of a burning star as a comet. Consider the figurative use, the symbolism that men have used to compare Alexander the Great's very short military career to that of a comet.

Comment: I take issue with your exclusive use of metaphors. It seems that everything has to be sieved through a metaphor in your world view. Nothing can be left at face value. Yes I agree when God makes a comparison it’s a comparison but to then extrapolate and take the liberty of always using the phrases metaphorically even if the text does not demand or require it, I take issue with that. I am fine with a secondary interpretation but not an exclusive interpretation to the exclusion of literal translations (unless it suits your worldview is the vibe in getting). Again I appreciate your different view

Comment: My exclusive use ?  These are God's metaphors and similes.  I do not try to find metaphors where they don't exist.  A lot of the Bible is literal, but His prophesies use a lot of figurative, symbolic language, and they contain a lot of His metaphors.  I don't invent them.

Comment: There is no indication that Rev8:10,11 are figurative and the passages you link to in the OT do not deny that he is an angel while the passage in Rev does not say he was of the earth and should be read figuratively. You have imputed your biases onto the text, for reasons you feel are justified. I do not consider them justified reasons nor true nor consistent, if the previous portion is a metaphor then the men dying ought to also be a metaphor so as to mean something other than men dying literally. But it seems it’s a pick and choose. You might not appreciate my feedback. I’ll stop. Thank you